# What's the term for a DB table that consists of foreign keys only?

Tags: database, terminology

Here's an example of such a table:

```
item_tag_relationships(item_id, tag_id);
```

Comment: **Many-To-Many** relationship table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen it called a few things:

- Junction table
- Join table
- Linker table

Answer (score 2):

I usually call it a join table, or a many-to-many join table if I'm feeling expansive.

Answer (score 1):

Junction table.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table

Comment: I usually use the term link table but this is the right one for me

Answer (score 0):

```
Associative Entity
```

In a schema design point of view... But it doesn't necessarily only contain foreign keys but usually as a buffer to link many to many relationships with each other.

Answer (score 0):

I think its famous name is junction table